# Replacing only certain values of a column based on condition of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have df below as:

```
name                flag 
company night      night
company day          day
dark night         night
night day both     night
night day both     night
```

How can I change the flag column to say both for all rows in the name column where the word both exists?

Desired output:

```
  name              flag 
company night      night
company day          day
dark night         night
night day both      both
night day both      both
```

used the methods below, but both use the first value in the row and dont correctly map to both for the applicable rows

method1:

```
r = '(both|night|day)'

c = dict(both = 'Both', night='Night', day='Day')

dfc['Identifier'] = dfc['NAME'].str.lower().str.extract(r, expand=False).map(c)
```

method2:

```
conditions = [dfc["NAME"].str.lower().str.contains("night"), 
               dfc["NAME"].str.lower().str.contains("day"),
               dfc["NAME"].str.lower().str.contains("both")]

values = [ 'night', 'day', 'both']
    
dfc["identifiter"] = np.select(conditions, values, default=np.nan)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.contains` to create a boolean Series and use it as a condition in `np.where` to assign values to "flag" column:

```
import numpy as np
df['flag'] = np.where(df['name'].str.contains('both'), 'both', df['flag'])
```

Another option is to `loc` instead:

```
df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('both'), 'flag'] = 'both'
```

Output:

```
             name   flag
0   company night  night
1     company day    day
2      dark night  night
3  night day both   both
4  night day both   both
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use list comprehensions.

```
dfc['Identifier']=['both' if 'both' in y else x for x,y in zip(df['flag'],df['name'])
```